# How do you rearrange text within a string from a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, string

**Solution I am looking for:**
I would like to rearrange words within the text string results such that the job title is moved from the end of the string to the beginning of the string for each line item.

Currently, I am retrieving data from an external medical database query (**$query**). However, I cannot make any changes to the database or to the MySQL query statement itself.

The **$query** is retrieved and I then place the results in a **$data** array via the following command:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){$data[] = $row;}
```

I then change all the job titles to uppercase in the **$data** array as follows:

```
$job_01 = 'anesthesiologist';
$job_02 = 'dentist';
$job_03 = 'general practitioner';
$job_04 = 'internist';
$job_05 = 'lawyer';
$job_06 = 'manager';
$job_07 = 'pediatrician';
$job_08 = 'psychiatrist';

$replace_01 = 'ANESTHESIOLOGIST';
$replace_02 = 'DENTIST';
$replace_03 = 'GENERAL PRACTITIONER';
$replace_04 = 'INTERNIST';
$replace_05 = 'LAWYER';
$replace_06 = 'MANAGER';
$replace_07 = 'PEDIATRICIAN';
$replace_08 = 'PSYCHIATRIST';

$searchArray = array($job_01, $job_02, $job_03, $job_04, $job_05, $job_06, $job_07, $job_08);
$replaceArray = array($replace_01, $replace_02, $replace_03, $replace_04, $replace_05, $replace_06, $replace_07, $replace_08);

for ($i=0; $i<=count($data)-1; $i++) {
 $line[$i] = str_ireplace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $data[$i]));
}
```

The final output is in the following line item text string format:

**Example Query results (4 line items)**

```
California Long time medical practitioner  -  ANESTHESIOLOGIST 55yr
New York Specializing in working with semi-passive children - PEDIATRICIAN (doctor) 42yr
Nevada Currently working in a new medical office - PSYCHIATRIST 38yr
Texas Represents the medical-liability industry - LAWYER (attorney) 45yr
```

I would like to rearrange these results such that I can output the data to my users in the following format by moving the **job title** to the **beginning** of each line item as in:

**Desired results (usually over 1000 items)**

```
ANESTHESIOLOGIST - California Long time medical practitioner  - 55yr
PEDIATRICIAN - New York Specializing in working with semi-passive children - (doctor) 42yr
PSYCHIATRIST - Nevada Currently working in a new medical office - psychiatrist 38yr
LAWYER - Texas Represents the medical-liability industry - lawyer (attorney) 45yr
```

Ideally, if possible, it would also be nice to have the **age** moved to the **beginning** of the text string results as follows:

**Ideal Results**

```
55yr - ANESTHESIOLOGIST - California Long time medical practitioner
42yr - PEDIATRICIAN - New York Specializing in working with semi-passive children - (doctor)
38yr - PSYCHIATRIST - Nevada Currently working in a new medical office - psychiatrist
45yr - LAWYER - Texas Represents the medical-liability industry - lawyer (attorney)
```

Comment: Instead of numbered variables, consider using arrays. PHP has them and - how practical! - `str_replace` or `preg_replace` and friends supports those, too! This will help you to get part of it more quickly into order so to better concentrate of the how not on the typing.

Comment: What is your table structure and what query are you using to select from it?

Comment: @GordonM Currently, I am retrieving data from an external medical database query ($query). However, I cannot make any changes to the database or to the MySQL query statement itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to extract and rearrange the array:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=count($data)-1; $i++) {
    $line[$i] = str_ireplace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $data[$i]));
    // variant a, complete line
    if(preg_match_all('/(.*)\s+-\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)yr$/', $line[$i],$matches)) {
        $line[$i] = $matches[3][0].'yr - '.$matches[2][0].' - '.$matches[1][0];
    // variant b, a line with age, but no jobtitle
    } elseif(preg_match_all('/(.*)\s+-\s+(\d+)yr$/', $line[$i],$matches)) {
        $line[$i] = $matches[2][0].'yr - '.$matches[1][0];
    // variant c, no age
    } elseif(preg_match_all('/(.*)\s+-\s+(.*)$/', $line[$i],$matches)) {
        $line[$i] = $matches[2][0].' - '.$matches[1][0];
    }
    // in other cases (no age, no jobtitle), the line is not modified at all.        
}
```

Comment: Almost works - I notice that if the string does not contain either the job title or the age the results are "yr - -" and the rest of the text string is removed.

Comment: For sure, the regular expression I used, can't handle missing parts, can you provide some code, to show all possible exceptions / variants of your text lines?

Comment: California Long time medical practitioner  -  55yr  

    New York Specializing in working with semi-passive children - PEDIATRICIAN (doctor) 42yr  
 
    Nevada Currently working in a new medical office - PSYCHIATRIST  
  
    Texas Represents the medical-liability industry - LAWYER (attorney) 45yr

Comment: I cannot seem to format the comments correctly. The only possible variants would be either or both a missing job title and or age.

Comment: @Sammy I just updated the answer. The regular expression might not be perfect (I recommend to do some optimization on them), but they should match your request.

Comment: This is much better. The only variant that did not rearrange is where the job title is not present but the age is present. The only other difference is that where the job title is followed by the text in the parentheses, both the job title and parentheses text is moved to the beginning as in 45yr - LAWYER (attorney)

Comment: However I really appreciate your time and effort